# Diappearence of icon of applications and folders

Tags: icons

I ran the following command on my Ubuntu 18.04.1:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all ubuntu-mono
```

After that, I restarted my system. Later, the icons of the terminal and folders are changed. How can I get back to the normal state?

Comment: Please ignore my wrong close flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My general rule of thumb when I remove something and something else breaks I put it back. So...

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-mono
```

...will hopefully get you icons back the way they were.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with this command it can resolve the issue

```
apt --fix-broken install
```